# Custom org-ellipsis is underlined

Tags: org-mode

This is rather strange though it seems merely an aesthetic issue.

I use something like

```
(setq org-ellipsis "  ")
```

to customize the ellipsis. However, whatever characters I choose, there is always a line under the new "ellipsis". For the above setting, it simply shows like this

```
* a Title___
```

I have tried to start emacs at the terminal with `-q` option, but the problem always exists. Notice that the underline does not appear if I just use the default `...`. I actually had this problem for some time now, and once in a while, a new update in org can eliminate the annoying underline, but then again it appears in the next update. My org is up to date as of today (8/23/2018). I'm using macOS high Sierra.

Can someone give me advice on how to remove the underline?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlining is part of the face `org-ellipsis`. Please note that the variable `org-ellipsis` and the face `org-ellipsis` are two different things!
You can change the appearance of the customized ellipsis with:
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-face` <kbd>RET</kbd> `org-ellipsis` <kbd>RET</kbd>

The face `org-ellipsis` has no influence if the standard outline ellipsis is used, i.e., the **variable** `org-ellipsis` is set to nil.

Comment: or you can do `(set-face-underline 'org-ellipsis nil)` if you want to code your customization.